# How to pull the most recent change on an item in Excel using arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to pull the most recent change to an item from a list of values and dates.

I've pasted a URL below for the image of the spreadsheet I'm currently working on.
This is currently in the top left of the spreadsheet, starting in cell A1.

I am trying to display in column C the "New Value" where columns A and E match, and where it is the most recent date in column F before the date listed in column B.

```
For C2, it would be 1.99
For C3, it would be 2.99
For C4, it would be 3.99
```

I'm trying to use INDEX, MATCH, and MAX to create an array and return the row number,
This is what my formula currently looks like:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$4,MAX(MATCH(1,(($E$2:$E$4=A2)*($F$2:$F$4<B2)),0)),4)
```

However I can't quite get it to display the correct values.
When I evaluate the formula, it looks like the array is evaluating correctly,
However I am having a difficult time because where it says {1,1,0} for C3, it will only result in the first match.

How can I change this array formula to only look at the last match row?

[image: Spreadsheet Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MAXIFS inside a SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,E:E,A2,F:F,MAXIFS(F:F,F:F,"<="&B2,E:E,A2))
```

[image]

IF one does not have MAXIFS, we can replace with AGGREGATE:

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,E:E,A2,F:F,AGGREGATE(14,7,$F$2:$F$4/(($F$2:$F$4<=B2)*(E2:E44=A2)),1))
```

---

or if one has the Dynamic Array Formula:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(E:H,(E:E=A2)*(F:F<=B2)),2,-1),1,4)
```

[image]